# C# compiler fails with misleading error when calling generic extension method with a dynamic argument

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, compiler-errors

While reading **Jon Skeet**'s book **C# In Depth 4th Edition**, I was doing some tests on dynamic binding limitations related to extension methods. 
As Jon says in that chapter, dynamic binding is not supported for extension methods in .NET, so the compiler prevents us from passing a dynamic value as an argument by raising the appropriate error CS1973. So for the following code:

```
//Provided this extension method
public static int GetFoo(this List<int> target, int value) => value * 10;

//And the following code at the call site
dynamic d = 1;
var items = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = items.GetFoo(d); //Error CS1973 as expected because
                              //we passed a dynamic argument
```

The error message is straightforward:

> *`List<int>` has no applicable method named `GetFoo` but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be
>   dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or
>   calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.*

No surprise until now. **But** if we change slightly the extension method to make it generic in order to accept a `List<T>` instead of `List<int>`, the compiler raises now a different error CS1929.

```
//The generic version of 'GetFoo' seen above
public static int GetFooGeneric<T>(this List<T> target, int value) => value * 10;

//Unexpectedly, the following call raises error CS1929 (instead of CS1973)
var result = items.GetFooGeneric(d);
```

And the error message is, in my opinion, as misleading as senseless:

> `List<int>` does not contain a definition for `GetFooGeneric` and the best
>   extension method overload `Extensions.GetFooGeneric<T>(List<T>, int)` requires a receiver of type `List<T>`.

Misleading because it hides the non-support of dynamic binding for extension methods, and it doesn't make sense to have an instance of type `List<T>` as the receiver to call the extension method on.

**Does anyone know what's happening behind the scenes that makes the compiler raise this misleading error message?**

---

**PS:** As a side note, if we supply the type argument for that same generic method, the compiler then raises the appropriate error CS1973 again as expected.

```
//By helping the compiler explicitly, it raises CS1973 appropriately
var result = items.GetFooGeneric<int>(d);
```

Comment: When you create extension method for `List<T>` it can not be called for `List<int>` without telling method what is `T`. That's why you are able to call with `GetFooGeneric<int>`. `best extension method overload Extensions.GetFooGeneric<T>(List<T>, int) requires a receiver of type List<T>` error message says the same thing..

Comment: If I'd be using `dynamic` myself, then I'd just call `items.GetFooGeneric((int)d)`. When you mix several errors it's somewhat unexpected what compiler will tell. The error you see is produced by another similar scenario without `dynamic` where it probably is very valid. Since you add `dynamic` you get confusing error, your fault.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya In most cases the compiler has the ability to infer the type of `T`, which would be the case even here if we pass a statically typed argument for the `int value` parameter. Another common example of type inference is when you call linq methods on a `List<T>`.

Comment: @Sinatr I agree that casting `d` to `int` will remove the problem of dynamic binding altogether in my contrived example. But what if the `value` parameter were also of type `dynamic` as follows `GetFooGeneric<T>(List<T>, dynamic)` ? This would still raise error CS1929 which is misleading us away from the real problem (dynamic binding unsupported for extension methods).

Comment: Method parameter `int Value` is just a parameter of type integer. It has nothing to do with `T`. So it can not infer `T` as integer at compile time.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Absolutely with you! but what I meant is that by passing a statically typed argument for the `value` parameter, this will remove both errors CS1973 and CS1929, so the compiler can then infer the type of `T` **from the type argument of the generic list** (which happens to be a `List<int>` in the example). Thank you for your feedback about this side-discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ouch. That's really bad! I don't recall if that one was my fault or not, but you are definitely right that this is a terrible error message.

It *possibly* is a result of some heuristics we put into the analyzer to deal with situations where you are actually typing the code in the editor and we need to do type inference on an incomplete or wrong call to an extension method in order to get the IntelliSense right; perhaps that is interacting badly with the dynamic argument?  But I would need to actually look at the code to refresh my memory there.

If I have time later today I'll look at the Roslyn sources and see if I recognize this code path.

I know that is not much of an answer to your question, but I haven't debugged through that code path since at least 2012 so my recall of those design choices is not what it once was. :)

Answer (score -1):

You write: `GetValueGeneric<T>(this List<T> target, int value)` Note that you write **Value**

Calling `items.GetFooGeneric(d);` will result in CS1929 because your function does not exist.

I tryied  `items.GetValueGeneric(d);` and it gives CS1973

Comment: Actually it was a mistaping error when I adapted my own code to be postable. Even though, it would raise error CS1061. Thank you for pointing out this copy-paste mistake.

Comment: was not sure about mistaping or not, but i don't have enough reputation to comment